# How to install Polynote on Windows?

Tags: python, ipython, scala, windows

I've been searching around the Internet for a while but I have not been able to find detailed instructions on how to install [Polynote](https://polynote.org/) (the polyglot notebook
with first-class Scala support) for Windows with mixing multiple languages, Python and Scala.

- [Github Link for Polynote](https://github.com/polynote/polynote).
- [Official Website](https://polynote.org/).

According to the official website:

> Polynote is currently only tested on Linux and MacOS, using the Chrome browser as a client. We hope to be testing other platforms and browsers soon. Feel free to try it on your platform, and be sure to let us know about any issues you encounter by filing a bug report

I would really appreciate it if anyone here can share his/her method if he/she
had successfully installed Polynote on Windows, either from Virtual Machines
(VMware/Virtualbox) or directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different from VMware or Virtualbox, but Polynote in Docker is supported by the developers and they have created a number of ready-made Docker images - [more info here](https://github.com/polynote/polynote/tree/master/docker), although the instructions are targeted at a Linux host. Below are the instructions modified for a Windows host:

Once you have [Docker installed](https://docs.docker.com/install/), make a folder somewhere on your host system, e.g. `C:\polynote`:

```
cd \
mkdir polynote
```

Then create a text file `config.yml` in that folder, with the contents:

```
listen:
  host: 0.0.0.0
```

Then, you can get the container running with a single command - although make sure you customise the paths to your config file and working folder:

```
docker run --rm -it -e PYSPARK_ALLOW_INSECURE_GATEWAY=1 
        -p 127.0.0.1:8192:8192 
        -p 127.0.0.1:4040-4050:4040-4050 
        -v C:/polynote:/opt/config 
        -v C:/path/to/your/working/folder:/opt/polynote/notebooks
        polynote/polynote:latest 
        --config /opt/config/config.yml
```

This exposes some ports to the host machine, mounts the folder with your config file into the container, mounts your working folder in the container at `/opt/polynote/notebooks`, pulls the latest Polynote Docker image and tells Docker to use your custom config file.

Once the container is spun up, you can use your web browser to access Polynote at http://localhost:8192/.

Answer (score 0):

> It works with Linux and MacOS only

according to [this](https://medium.com/@kyleake/review-polynote-an-ide-for-netflix-data-scientists-and-machine-learning-researchers-463582cab659).

You could set up a Virtual Machine, install Linux on it and run Polynote there.

Answer (score 0):

I created a script to run Polynote in it's current version on Windows (0.3.11).
https://github.com/moritzbaumotte/polynote-windows-inofficial